# The Encrypt library requires the Mcrypt extension after initializing library

Tags: php, codeigniter, mcrypt

I am using php version 7 and using codeigniter framework so as per requirement I am encoding the string using :

```
$this->encrypt->encode('some_text');
```

I have called library using constructor

```
$this->load->library('encrypt');
$this->load->library('encryption');
```

but getting error:

```
The Encrypt library requires the Mcrypt extension
```

Comment: If you have composer installed try doing `composer require phpseclib/mcrypt_compat`

Comment: @neubert no idon't have installed composer

Comment: why codeigniter encrypt  is supporting only php 5 not php 7 it is working in php 5

Comment: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mcrypt-viking-funeral explains why it's no longer working. It looks like there are no Windows releases for the mcrypt PECL extension (https://pecl.php.net/package/mcrypt). If there were Windows releases it'd look like https://pecl.php.net/package/ssh2 . As such I think https://github.com/phpseclib/mcrypt_compat is going to be your only option.